# Javascript/Jquery: How to get the src value of the images with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to get the src value of the images with the same class and write/output them into an empty div?

For Example:

```
<body>
    <img class="class1" src="http://www.mysite.com/img/image1.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="">
    <img class="class1" src="http://www.mysite.com/img/image2.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="">
    <img class="class1" src="http://www.mysite.com/img/image3.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="">
    <img class="class1" src="http://www.mysite.com/img/image4.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="">
    <img class="class1" src="http://www.mysite.com/img/image5.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="">
    <img class="class2" src="http://www.mysite.com/img/image6.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="">
    <img class="class2" src="http://www.mysite.com/img/image7.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="">
    <img class="class2" src="http://www.mysite.com/img/image8.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="">
    <img class="class2" src="http://www.mysite.com/img/image9.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="">
    <img class="class2" src="http://www.mysite.com/img/image10.jpg" width="168" height="168" alt="">

    <div id="print-src">
             <!-- Print Result Here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Result (If I only want to retrieve src values for images with a class of class1):

```
<body>
     ...........................

    <div id="print-src">
        http://www.mysite.com/img/image1.jpg
        http://www.mysite.com/img/image2.jpg
        http://www.mysite.com/img/image3.jpg
        http://www.mysite.com/img/image4.jpg
        http://www.mysite.com/img/image5.jpg
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var prn = $('#print-src');
$('img.class2').each(function () {
    prn.append('<p>' + this.src + '</p>');
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5BPh8/1/)

Comment: Almost, but they're not meant to be separate divs tho according to the example.

Comment: @Andy, you could use `prn.append('<p>' + this.src + '</p>');` or `prn.append(this.src + '</br>');`